# Обновление картинки OpenGL в Android при выводе через SurfaceView

Tags: android, opengl, glsurfaceview

Добрый день! Строю фигуру в OpenGL и вывожу через SurfaceView на экран. Изначально координаты фигуры ( X и Y) задаются кодом, но хочу сделать, чтобы они вводились с экрана. Для этого сделал ввод через EditTExt, координаты получаю и передаю в OpenGl, но получается, что нужно как-то перестроить фигуру с новыми координатами, а как это сделать?